# How can I make a new Excel sheet containing unique individual ID and credentials based on multiple sheet records?

Tags: excel, vba

The computer in my office uses Windows 7 and Microsoft Office 2003(Excel 2003)

Say for example I have the table below in a sheet named JANUARY

[image: JANUARY]

and another named FEBRUARY.

[image: FEBRUARY]

How can I make a "database" of these people?
Something like this

[image: result]

What I have tried was the Data - > Filter - > Advanced Filter method to copy only the the unique ones into another sheet but it doesn't even seem to work even on a simple test data

Comment: Sounds like something that would be better done with an actual database. What have you tried? Please include your code in your question.

Comment: I'm not really a programmer. Actually, this is the daily statistic of patient's name and MRN and their respective treatment separated in sheets(month). They(my colleague) have gotten used to just keying in the data manually(directly) onto Excel spreadsheets. As you can probably imagine , this very slow, and really we don't have time doing this

Right now I'm trying to turn all these entered data into an excel "database" so later I could spruce up some VBA GUI data entry Form that could update the "database" later on and just use that database to quickly pull information from previous entries

Comment: @braX , I've only tried the Advanced Filter method so far but I'm still trying it out. I have a feeling that there is probably a way easier way to do this but I'm not really sure what to search for

Comment: I see. Well, when you have code you need help with, you can come back and ask some specific questions about it. Questions like this are out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @brax just because the Q isn't about debugging existing code doesn't automatically make it off topic.

Comment: @nostalgia there are many ways to approach this. One would be to copy the entire tables from each source sheet, then use Remove Duplicates (that may have been added to Excel after 2003, so you may have to code a version yourself).

Comment: @brax [here's a better explanation of why Q's like this are ok](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392433/445425)

Comment: You can record a macro while performing your task.                                                                                                                `1st` _ Select the Developer Tab
`2nd` _ Select Record Macro
    `Step A _ Add a blank worksheet
    `Step B _ Copy all data from each worksheet and paste to the new Worksheet directly below the previous copied data
    `Step C _ Select all columns on the new worksheet - Select the Data Tab _ Select Remove Duplicates
`3rd` _ Select `Stop Recording` _ Select `Macro` _ Select `Macro1` and clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sheet and Name it Combine

You can loop through the sheets and send the data to sheets("Combine").
Then remove the duplicates base on column A

```
Sub GetStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Combine")

    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
            With sh
                .Range("A2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
                        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End With
        End If
    Next sh

    ws.Columns("A:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the `Range.RemoveDuplicates` method appeared until Excel 2007. *(I know the Excel method did not)*.  If that is the case, you can code a method using the Collection or Dictionary object.

Comment: I think this might be it, I will try tomorrow. @RonRosenfield , okay thanks for the heads up, I'm willing to install 2007 or use another PC just to do that .

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ah yes, I will give another option for xl'03